# Listbox text value conversion to a numeric value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a listbox to list 8 model numbers the code below does this for me

```
Dim BS4Q As Double
Dim BS6Q As Double
Dim BS8Q As Double
Dim BS10Q As Double
Dim BS12Q As Double
Dim BSQ36 As Double
Dim BSQ54 As Double
Dim BSQ96 As Double
ListBox1.AddItem "BS4Q"
ListBox1.AddItem "BS6Q"
ListBox1.AddItem "BS8Q"
ListBox1.AddItem "BS10Q"
ListBox1.AddItem "BS12Q"
ListBox1.AddItem "BSQ36"
ListBox1.AddItem "BSQ54"
ListBox1.AddItem "BSQ96"



End Sub
```

The next thing I need to happen is for a user entered number be multiplied by a number assigned to each of the BS texts

```
Dim BS4Q As Double
Dim BS6Q As Double
Dim BS8Q As Double
Dim BS10Q As Double
Dim BS12Q As Double
Dim BSQ36 As Double
Dim BSQ54 As Double
Dim BSQ96 As Double
Dim N3 As Double
Dim Answer As Double


BS4Q = 0.7
BS6Q = 0.9
BS8Q = 1.1
BS10Q = 1.5
BS12Q = 1.8
BSQ36 = 0.1
BSQ54 = 0.2
BSQ96 = 0.4
  Answer = val(TextBox7) * (ListBox1.Value)
  Worksheets(1).Range("E22").Value = Answer
End Sub
```

It seems to function as I want except for the multiplication, it is not getting the numeric value in the equation rather the text value. If I replace the (ListBox1.Value) with just any number the equation works so I think it is just a conversion I am missing.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear what do you add to your listbox. The number 0.7 (for BS4Q) or the literal string "BS4Q". In the latter case it is obvious because it doesn't work. A group of letters "BS4Q" has no meaning in a math expression.

Comment: So it is not possible to have a text value displayed as the Listbox on the worksheet but be referenced to the number?

Comment: It is possible, you just need to map the visible text value to the multiplication number somewhere. You could do this on a hidden sheet or in code.

Comment: I'd prefer it in code, so id have to take the Listbox1.Value to a seperate string and use some if logic?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following  function

```
Function myMult(inpStr As String, inpMult As Double) As Double

    Select Case inpStr

        Case "BS4Q"
            myMult = 4 * inpMult

        Case "BS6Q"
            myMult = 6 * inpMult

        ' add the remaining cases

        Case Else
            myMult = 0
    End Select

End Function
```

like that

```
Answer = mymult( ListBox1.Value, val(TextBox7))
```

**2nd solution approach** You could use a regular expression to extract the first number from your string with the following function.

```
Function getFirstNumber(inp As String) As Double

    ' In order to use Regex in VBA, you first have to set the reference 
    ' in the VBE editor. In the VBE editor, go to 
    ' Tools>References>Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions.
    Dim regEx As RegExp
    Set regEx = New RegExp

    With regEx
       .Pattern = "\d+"
       If .Test(inp) Then
           getFirstNumber = .Execute(inp)(0)
       Else
           getFirstNumber = 0
       End If
    End With

End Function
```

And in your code you would write

```
Answer = getFirstNumber(ListBox1.Value) * val(TextBox7)
```

Comment: ok this definitely got it closer! the multiplication works just gotta sort out my listbox population and duplication! thank you!!

Comment: Not sure how that 2nd approach would work, the number in the string doesn't match the multiplier?

Comment: @jamheadart: Yes, right, if the number in the string does not correspond to the multiplier the second approach is not working. So, OP has to use ths first approach and replace the numbers there with the right ones. But the post is not that clear about the multipliers, at least for me.

Comment: I just read it as `ListBox1.AddItem "BS4Q"` then "user entered number be multiplied by a number assigned to each of the BS text" where `BS4Q = 0.7` etc. so your answer should be more like `Case "BS4Q": myMult = 0.7 * inpMult` instead of 4.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right and the OP just needs to adjust the first version with his values.

Answer (score -1):

Use, please the next function to extract numbers from string. If works for numbers having more than a digit:

```
Function GetNumbers(strText As String)
 Dim i As Long, strRes As String

 For i = 1 To Len(strText)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(strText, i, 1)) Then strRes = strRes & Mid(strText, i, 1)
 Next i
 GetNumbers = strRes
End Function
```

You can use it in the next way:

```
Answer = CDbl(TextBox7) * GetNumbers(ListBox1.Value)
```

Comment: The value in the text string is not the multiplier!

Comment: @jamheadart: You are right! I was confused by the line `Answer = val(TextBox7) * (ListBox1.Value)` and I thought that the textbox text must be converted to number. Adapted the code accordingly. Thanks!